# How to display the log of query statements in the log?

Tags: cnosdb

How to display the log of query statements in the log?

For example, I sent a query request:

```sql
curl -i -u "root:password" -H "Accept: application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:8902/api/v1/sql?db=usage_schema" -d 'SELECT * from coord_data_in limit 1'
```

I would like to see a record of this request in the log. What configurations should I enable?

I carefully looked at each item in the [configuration](https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/blob/main/config/config.toml), but did not find the relevant configuration.

I would like to be able to see the details of my request in a log, such as the following one:

```
xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xx.xxxxxxxxZ  INFO query: QUERY: /xxxx/data_nodes_metrics/xxxx :{"user":"root","db":"usage_schema","query":"SELECT * from coord_data_in limit 1"}
```